# jquery causes flickering in IE

Tags: jquery

Hi I am using jquery to expand/collapse my links.For this I am using show(), hide() functions from jquery. If i collapse the link I see flickering for a second. Can anyone please suggest me how to avoid this plz.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a demo or working link?

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues with accordion plugins and I solved them by adding position:relative to the containing div's css.

Comment: I already have position:relative in my css. But I still have the problem.